# Example of a Jordan homomorphism that is not a homomorphism or antihomomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Can anyone please provide an example of a Jordan homomorphism (preferably on $n\times n$ matrices over a commutative ring) that is not already a homomorphism or antihomomorphism?

An obvious Jordan homomorphism is the transpose map, which is not a homomorphism but an antihomomorphism. A true example would be much appreciated.

A linear map $J:A \rightarrow B$ on two algebras $A$ and $B$ is called a Jordan homomorphism if $J(a^2) = J(a)^2$ for all $a \in A$. If $A$ and $B$ are unital and $1+1$ is invertible in $B$ then this is equivalent to 
$$J(ab+ba) = J(a)J(b)+J(b)J(a)$$
for all $a,b \in A$.

Comment: Do you mean "transpose" rather than "trace"?

Comment: You are already aware of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-081-02/S0002-9947-1956-0076751-6/S0002-9947-1956-0076751-6.pdf) I suppose? It came up while I was researching, but I didn't manage to find an answer to your question in the time I spent skimming it.

Comment: I updated trace to transpose. I did look at the paper by Herstein but indeed they are not concrete examples.

Comment: This example answers my original question. Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with unity that contains an idempotent $e$. Then if $A$ and $B$ are $R$-algebras with a linear map $\theta: A \rightarrow B$ defined by
 $$\theta(a) = ea+(1-e)\varphi(a),$$

where $\varphi$ is an antiautomorphism of $A$, then $\theta$ is a Jordan homomorphism that is neither a homomorphism or antihomomorphism. This example appears in the exposition of *Jordan isomorphisms of triangular matrix
algebras over a connected commutative ring* (2000) by Beidar, Bresar, and Chebotar.